# tx fee exceeds the configured cap in a private ethereum sidechain

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, gas-price, sidechain

i need your help with this one. I have been struggling with the same issue for days now.

I'm getting this error response (tx fee exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether) when i try to set a relatively high gasPrice. While I can find many other transactions from other accounts sending very high gasPrice and there tx is mined and receipt status is `true`.

I'm using Web3JS to send the tx but I tried via simple CURL request and i get the same error.

Here is code example

```
const rawTx = {
    to: '0x21307398....',
    data: data,
    gasPrice: '4531000000000',
    gasLimit: 400000,
    nonce: txCount,
};

const signedTx = await client.account.signTransaction(rawTx);

await client.rpc.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
    .on('transactionHash', async (hash) => {
        console.log(hash);
    }).then(r => {
        console.log(r);
    });
```

Comment: What client are you using? Geth has a configuration option that limits how much you can pay in transaction fees (it is to avoid expensive mistakes).

Comment: This is in a ethereum sidechain, i don't run any node locally I just use public RPC endpoint.
I was wondering if i have to run my own node and configure it as you suggested

Comment: I'd suggest to contact the node administrator to ask for recommended gasPrice and gas limits.